# How to get the magento category meta description on catalog list page

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to show the category description of each category dynamically on category list page. First I try to set condition for each category but that was not perfect solution late I found a best way to do this so I thought I should share it to prevent someone time.

Answer (score 0):

By using below code you can check the current category on catalog list template of your theme.

```
$metaDescription = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getMetaDescription(); 
if(!empty($metaDescription)): ?>
<div class="col-md-12 std">
    <p><?php echo $metaDescription; ?></p>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Follow the screenshot to add meta description of category in magento admin section.
[image]

Comment: `echo Mage::registry('current_category')->getMetaDescription()`